# Gnuplot cant create a jpeg

Tags: gnuplot

im trying to save a graph as a jpeg but for some reason i cant get it to work. Im following the example in the Manning Gnuplot in action but no jpeg seems to be created when i replot. Below is the code, if someone could point out where im going wrong i would really appreciate it.

```
gnuplot> plot sin(x)
gnuplot> set terminal jpeg
Terminal type set to 'jpeg'
Options are 'nocrop font "arial,12" fontscale 1.0 size 640,480 '

gnuplot> set output "c:\Users\*****\Desktop\sinxplot.jpeg"
gnuplot> replot
gnuplot> set terminal wxt enhanced
Terminal type set to 'wxt'
Options are '0 enhanced'
gnuplot> set output
gnuplot>
```

FYI, Im using version 4.6 patchlevel 0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`gnuplot` uses `\` as escape character in strings, so that probably messes up your path.
try using single quotes instead of double, or use `\\` as path separator.

(oh, and by the way: jpeg isn't really goot for plots because of it's compression algorithm which results in having artefacts, png is much better here.)

Comment: Single quote with \ vs \\ works perfectly. Thanks also for the tip regarding jpeg vs png, much appreciated